# Is there any dex creator on android?

Tags: android, dex, utility

I wonder if there is any dx utility available on android platform. I am trying to generate .dex file from within android environment. Can anyone help in this?
Thanks.

Comment: it is under: `<android_sdk_home>/build_tools/<version>/dx`

Comment: you can easy extract .dex file from .apk file

Comment: no no.. what i am asking is that i am looking for dx utility on the android environment on mobile so that i can make an app similar to 'Apk Creator'. Any help..

Answer (score 1):

dx is implemented in java, so you should be able to trivially use it on android.

As a quick proof of concept, you can try:

```
dx --dex --output=dx.dex $ANDROID_SDK/build-tools/23.0.1/lib/dx.jar
adb push dx.dex /sdcard/
adb shell dalvikvm -cp /sdcard/dx.dex com.android.dx.command.Main
```

To actually integrate dx into your application, you could take a couple of different approaches.

- You could simply bundle that dx.dex with your app and then execute it with the dalvikvm command like above
- You could bundle that dx.dex file, and then use DexClassLoader to load it into your process
- You could use dx.jar as a library when building your apk, so that the dx classes included in your main classes.dex and are directly available for use

Comment: So it means that if i write a simple hello world! code in java on my android phone then i can build an apk of this hello-world program on my phone? btw where can i find dx utility on android os?

Comment: My answer explains how to convert dx to a dex file and put it on an Android device and run it. You can't make a command line java program into an apk - but you can convert it to a dex file and run it from the shell on an android device with the "dalvikvm" command. e.g. the third command in my example above.